# Best Comprehensive Location Equipment for £5000?

Tags: budget, workflow, sound-devices, lavalier, wireless

Hi guys,

I'm wondering what you guys would pick if you wanted a comprehensive recording kit for small films, documentaries and SFX recording with a £5000 budget?

I already have a NTG-3 shotgun mic and a failing Fostex FR-2LE. I'm currently considering a sound devices 744t and 302 mixer but this almost brings me up to the price of a 788t! I find I almost always want 3-channel recording on set.

Also im looking for preferably two wireless lavs with that.

Any recommendations on what you guys would get with that budget? I am definitely on the right path with the sound devices? I have used a 702 before and really enjoyed the function and sound.

Also websites you guys use to buy gear?

Any advice appreciated,

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to just record everything separately or actually record a mix as well?

If you want to do both, you could go with the 744T (wonderful device!) and a mixer like the PSC Promix 6, which has not only 2 sets of XLR outputs (you can go to recorder and camera, or two camera, etc...), but also has Direct Outputs on each channel. It would allow you to do a mono mix and Isos for up to 3 channels (when paired with the 744T). More if you get a fancier recorder (ie - if you got an 8 channel [Deva](http://www.coffeysound.com/Zaxcom-Fusion-10-Recorder.html), [SD](http://www.coffeysound.com/Sound-Devices-788T-Portable-8-Track-Hard-Disk-Recorder.html), [Nagra](http://www.coffeysound.com/Nagra-VI-8-Channel-Digital-Audio-Recorder.html), or [Tascam](http://www.coffeysound.com/Tascam-DR-680-Recorder.html) ([another](http://www.coffeysound.com/Tascam-HS-P82-8-Channel-Recorder.html)) field recorder, you could do a stereo mix + 6 Iso channels).

If you want to just plug everything in and not mix, I'd just go with the 744T. Keep in mind that there are only 2 preamps on it. You'll need to go line in to the other two inputs (using TA3-F adapters). This works fine with most wireless, but if you have a mic level, you'll have to get a pre in front of it (mixer, mixpre, etc...)

If you want an all-in-one solution, you can go with the [788T](http://www.coffeysound.com/Sound-Devices-788T-Portable-8-Track-Hard-Disk-Recorder.html) (awesome), or the [Zaxcom Nomad](http://www.coffeysound.com/Zaxcom-Nomad.html) (also awesome). Both can multitrack as well as mix within the unit.

Nice thing about the 788T is that you can get two different control surfaces for it, as well as the CL-x accessories.

Nice thing about the Nomad is that it already has a decent control surface on the front panel, and it's dirt cheap for what you're getting!

As far as where to buy?

I buy most of my stuff from [B&H](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/) or [Coffey Sound](http://www.coffeysound.com/). There is also [TAI](http://taiaudio.com/catalog/), [Markertek](http://www.markertek.com/) and [Trew](http://www.trewaudio.com/). These are all in the USA though. Not sure about overseas.

Ebay works well too :-)

Happy hunting! Let me know if I can clarify or expand on anything for you.

Answer (score 1):

Get a Sonosax SX-R4? 
Pinknoise currently sell a used one with 6 months warranty for £3199 + VAT.
It has timecode, 4 great mic pres (8 channels of recording when using digital ins), and is built like a rock. A friend of mine has one and it's definitely a lovely device.
Unless you want a separate mixer, it will be the 'cheapest' way to go.

Comment: I checked this out, it looks like a really nice piece of kit. I'm tempted to get a separate mixer too so I could use it with my Fostex or Zoom H4N and also for Foley, as the preamps are much better than my Mbox1s! I'll def give that recorder a good thought and let you know how i get on. :)


Answer (score 1):

Hi Kyle,
If you want 4 channels XLR input then Daan's recommendation is very good. One thing i don't like about the SX-R4 is the ergonomics of the machine. It is something you really have to get used to and you already know the 702..
You're also thinking about 2 wireless lavs, right? A 744 is able to record that, just use the additional 2 Line inputs (mini xlr connectors required).

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, yeah the 744t looks great for my purposes and I really like the SD gear. Cheers